# How to avoid caching issue when using custom JavaScript and CSS deployed under _layouts?

Tags: javascript, css

On our farm, I'm deploying some JavaScript and CSS files under the `_layouts` folder.

I'm then referencing them, where it's required using a `<SharePoint:ScriptLink>` or a `<SharePoint:CssRegistration>` control :

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration 
    runat="server" 
    Name="/_layouts/styles/company/custom.css" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink 
    runat="server" 
    Name="/_layouts/scripts/company/custom.js" 
    Localizable="false" />
```

This is working fine.

However, these assets are cached in the client browser. When I deploy minor updates, I have to ask users to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to reload without the cache, but it's not an acceptable workaround.

Is there a way to ensure the latest version is loaded, without disabling the cache?

By now, I can see two possible solutions:

1. version the assets in the file name (`custom.1.0.css`, `custom.1.1.css`, ...): I don't like this solution because it requires to update every code that reference the asset
2. Add a "revision number" to the url. I can trick using this code :

   ```
   <SharePoint:CssRegistration 
       runat="server" 
       Name="/_layouts/styles/company/custom.css"
       id="customCss" />
   <SharePoint:ScriptLink 
       runat="server" 
       Name="/_layouts/scripts/company/custom.js" 
       Localizable="false"
       id="customJs" />
   ```

   And in the codebehind :

   ```
       private static readonly long g_AssemblyTimeStamp = File.GetCreationTime(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).Ticks;
       protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
       {
           customJs.Name += "?rev=" + g_AssemblyTimeStamp;
           customCss.Name += "?rev=" + g_AssemblyTimeStamp;
       }
   ```

   This adds to the script url something like `?rev=634946193703232026`. The browser then sees a new url and reload it, and still cache this file.

   This is working, but still requires some plumbing code to make it works.

Is there any clean solution to meet this requirement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is, to get rid of the starting "/" in your Name values.

***JS***

SharePoint will automatically check, if the js file changes and will append a custom query string with a revision number, just like it does with the internal js files, if you check the source of your website.
You just have to change the **Name** in your Scriptlink control like:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink 
    runat="server" 
    Name="scripts/company/custom.js" 
    Localizable="false"
    id="customJs" />
```

This will change the path to your custom.js on the website to s.th. like:

```
<script src="/_Layouts/scripts/company/custom.js?rev=HVORLc5FI20n7W90mjha3A%3D%3D"></script>
```

(If you have your JS files under _layouts/1033, you should set localizable to "true" and keep the Name path the same).

***CSS***

For CSS, the relative path starts under "/_layouts/1033/styles", so to get to "/_layouts" and make SharePoint take care of Cache Busting, you should change your CSSRegistration Name to the following

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration runat="server" Name="../../company/custom.css" id="customCss" />
```

This will change the path to your custom.css on the website to s.th. like:

```
<link id="CssRegistration2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_Layouts/1033/styles/../../scripts/company/custom.css?rev=p63%2BuzTeSJc22nVGNZ5zwg%3D%3D"/>
```

(For CSS, I am not sure, if you can use Localizable="False")

Interesting article:
http://community.rightpoint.com/blogs/viewpoint/archive/2012/02/24/cache-busting-with-the-sharepoint-cssregistration-control.aspx

Comment: After some years of practice, your answer is, with no hesitation, the actual correct answer. Thanks

Comment: Beware that this doesn't seem to work with SharePoint Online. The `_Layouts` folder which is used as a root for cache management is hosted on a global domain for all SPO sites `static.sharepointonline.com`.

Comment: @JonathanHolvey: indeed, adding files under the layouts folder is supported only in onpremise scenarios, as it requires access to the file system.

Comment: Just a follow up on why SP is appending `rev` key to `Name` in `ScriptLink`. It will append it always unless it begins with tilde key `~`.

Answer (score 15):

`SPUtility` provide us a method called - `MakeBrowserCacheSafeLayoutsUrl(string, boolean)` and other overload methods.

Based on last modification this itself generate a MD5 hash code and append it to css or js urls. We don't have to worry about finding version numbers or generating id based on creation date, this is already handled.

I have used this in my project for handling css caching for custom css. SharePoint internally does same for OOB css which are rendered by `CSSLink`.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
        CssRegistration cssRegistration1 = new CssRegistration();        
        cssRegistration1.After = "corev4.css";
        cssRegistration1.ConditionalExpression = "IE 7";
        cssRegistration1.Name = SPUtility.MakeBrowserCacheSafeLayoutsUrl("FolderBelowLayouts/Styles/CustomCss.css", false); //will be /_layouts/15/FolderBelowLayouts/Styles/CustomCss.css?rev=...
        Controls.Add(cssRegistration1);
        base.OnInit(e);
}
```

and for link tags you can directly do:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=SPUtility.MakeBrowserCacheSafeLayoutsUrl("FolderBelowLayouts/Styles/CustomCss.css", false)%>" />
```

Refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.makebrowsercachesafelayoutsurl.aspx

Comment: I don't think SPUtility.MakeBrowserCacheSafeLayoutsUrl is a good solution. Not a solution at all, really. It does generate ?rev= string after your file, but it does so only once. if you change your file it will not regenerate ?rev= string because ?rev part is stored in a private field in SPUtility.s_layoutsFileHashCache. This cache does not get purged during iisreset and after new wsp is installed. Please, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Just to update on Denis' comment (and his question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85984/is-sputility-makebrowsercachesafelayoutsurl-method-useful-at-all) - `MakeBrowserCacheSafeLayoutsUrl` works as advertised. The Cache is cleared with each IISRESET.

Comment: Update: It does work perfectly well. I take my words back. I've been using it for several years already and it seems to be the best choice for avoiding caching problems

Answer (score 3):

Steve,

there is no clean solution for your problem. Browsers cache files by url, you can avoid caching appending in query string unique value per deployment. For example

`_layouts/my_js_file.js?v=<current date>` - will be refreshed from cache when day changes

`_layouts/my_js_file.js?v=<GUID>` - if guid is generated on every request, this file should never cache

`_layouts/my_js_file.js?v=<product version>` - more preferable solution, browser will update cache on every new version that was deployed

Actually, ScriptLink should take care about this, internally it has a method that appends unique id into query string based on js file content, if content changed, hash is also changed and new unique id is generated.

I recommend you to read [this](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2011/11/avoiding-bugs-from-cached-javascript.html) article about your issue.

Comment: I don't understand. You stated that the scriptlink control will add the hash to the url automatically. This is not the case in my case. Is it possible that this does not occurs in subfolders or _layouts? Actually, my deployment is under _layouts/CustomerName/file...

Comment: @SteveB, if this is not expected behaviour for you, you should go away from `ScriptLink` and implement your own script control (`ScriptLink` is sealed, you can't extend it) with your logic.

Comment: Actually, I have a solution, which is described in my answer. Having to rewrite the script link completely won't be an improvement. Anyways, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a cleaner solution, but a couple of years back I did something similar for an Internet facing publishing site.

First, we were using SharePoint Server with the publishing infrastructure hence having a "/Style Library/" with major versioning enabled to store assets like images, CSS & JS files.

Then we created a "PlaceholderAdditionalPageHead" SharePoint delegate control with OnInit code to retrieve the last published major version number of the file in question and append it to the URL like you did.

This saved us from deploying files to "/_layouts/" and also no GAC deployment as we used an ASCX WebControl. Both were requirements set by higher-ups we couldn't get around.

Unfortunately, I can't get my hands on the code currently because I don't have a VM handy with the sourcecode repository holding that old project code. Hope it still helps a little bit...

**UPDATE:** I forgot to mention that the ASCX WebControl had to be deployed to the server. However, since our solution was part of a larger package we were allowed to deploy the ASCX to the server (otherwise we would have used a DocLib with inline code enabled per web.config). Sorry for missing that part first-hand.

Comment: thanks for your post. But I don't any problem to deploy under the layouts directory. In fact, I don't see how changing the deployment location may help to solve my issue (as you said, you had to add some plumbing code)

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an older question but I stumbled upon it because I wanted to know if the SOD system always added a random key to the end of the files to force them to always reload. Apparently, if you materially modify the file then the SOD system is supposed to trigger the generation of a new key. I haven't found this to be accurate.

What I did was make a function to generate my own random key. Very simple:

```
someNamespace.getScriptKey=function(){
    var k="";
    for(var i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
        var c=Math.floor(Math.random()*25)+97;
        k+=String.fromCharCode(c);
    }
    return k;
};
```

Now, wherever I want to link to a file I just use this type of pattern. If you want to tweak the getScriptKey() function to return a key based on the date or maybe on some constant value that you update whenever you deploy a new version, this is obviously possible and flexible. It is totally transparent; you know exactly how it works.

```
 var sKey='?'+someNamespace.getScriptKey();
 SP.SOD.registerSod('keyA.js','/any/path/to/files/keyA.min.js'+sKey);
 SP.SOD.registerSod('keyB.js','/siteassets/scripts/keyB.min.js'+sKey);
 SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['keyA.js','keyB.js'], function(){
  console.log('All files loaded');
 });
```